# 20.04 LTS, I was using GIMP and some how my default font got corrupted?

Tags: 20.04, fonts, gimp

[example screen shot of my font problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUZo5.png)

I was doing some graphic design using GIMP (posters, so large file sizes) and it froze my machine and I had to force reboot.  For some reason, this font is set as my default font on any Chrome page that doesn't have it's own stylesheet, in my MS Teams preview, etc etc... I've tried fixing it with GNOME Tweaks 3.34.0, I've rebuilt my font cache, etc etc... This has fixed it in MOST places, but not all (specifically, Teams, Mailspring emails, specifically if it's HTML and using sans-serif [see the fonts in the dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgN7H.png) , and LibreCalc if it's trying to display Arial   Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I wonder if you have installed a new font with bad metadata.  What is the output of `fc-match Arial` and `fc-match sans-serif`

Comment: Hi @MartinThornton  so, running that gave me what I expect for Arial, but sans-serif not so much:
`[~]$ fc-match Arial
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
Arial.ttf: "Arial" "Regular"
[~]$ fc-match sans-serif
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
GoudyBookletter1911.otf: "Goudy Bookletter 1911" "Regular"`

Comment: Is there any output from `echo "$FONTCONFIG_FILE"`?  If not, what is the output of `ls -l /etc/fonts/fonts.conf`

Comment: /etc/fonts/fonts.conf seems to be missing.  That said my computer is currently not booting anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the Microsoft core fonts installed?

If not:

```
sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Then, refresh the cache:

```
sudo fc-cache -vr
```

Comment: Thanks @cheer, after doing that, and restarting it seems to have fixed most of my issues!